# Fuzzy matching using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, fuzzy-search

I have a table **Persons** with personaldata and so on. There are lots of columns but the once of interest here are: `addressindex`, `lastname` and `firstname` where `addressindex` is a unique address drilled down to the door of the apartment.
So if I have 'like below' two persons with the `lastname` and one the `firstnames` are the same they are most likely duplicates.

I need a way to list these duplicates.

```
tabledata:

personid     1
firstname    "Carl"
lastname     "Anderson"
addressindex 1

personid     2
firstname    "Carl Peter"
lastname     "Anderson"
addressindex 1
```

I know how do this if I were to match exactly on all columns but I need fuzzy match to do the trick with (from the above example) a result like:

```
Row     personid      addressindex     lastname     firstname
1       2             1                Anderson     Carl Peter
2       1             1                Anderson     Carl
.....
```

Any hints on how to solve this in a good way?

Comment: BTW way, it is quite likely it is NOT the same person in the case given. Fathers and sons do live together at times you know.

Comment: This is always the problem with semi-clever address evaluation algorithms. You can make an assumption, but you can never be sure.

Comment: Good point although The descition is another issue based on the result of the fuzzy match.

Comment: @justSteve: I added a new answer proposing a more up-to-date possibility.

Answer (score 34):

I've found that the stuff SQL Server gives you to do fuzzy matching is pretty clunky.  I've had really good luck with my own CLR functions using the Levenshtein distance algorithm and some weighting.  Using that algorithm, I've then made a UDF called GetSimilarityScore that takes two strings and returns a score between 0.0 and 1.0.  The closer to 1.0 the match is, the better.  Then, query with a threshold of >=0.8 or so to get the most likely matches.  Something like this:

```
if object_id('tempdb..#similar') is not null drop table #similar
select a.id, (
    select top 1 x.id
   from MyTable x
   where x.id <> a.id
   order by dbo.GetSimilarityScore(a.MyField, x.MyField) desc
) as MostSimilarId
into #similar
from MyTable a

select *, dbo.GetSimilarityScore(a.MyField, c.MyField)
from MyTable a
join #similar b on a.id = b.id
join MyTable c on b.MostSimilarId = c.id
```

Just don't do it with really large tables.  It's a slow process.

Here's the CLR UDFs:

```
''' <summary>
''' Compute the distance between two strings.
''' </summary>
''' <param name="s1">The first of the two strings.</param>
''' <param name="s2">The second of the two strings.</param>
''' <returns>The Levenshtein cost.</returns>
<Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction()> _
Public Shared Function ComputeLevenstheinDistance(ByVal string1 As SqlString, ByVal string2 As SqlString) As SqlInt32
    If string1.IsNull OrElse string2.IsNull Then Return SqlInt32.Null
    Dim s1 As String = string1.Value
    Dim s2 As String = string2.Value

    Dim n As Integer = s1.Length
    Dim m As Integer = s2.Length
    Dim d As Integer(,) = New Integer(n, m) {}

    ' Step 1
    If n = 0 Then Return m
    If m = 0 Then Return n

    ' Step 2
    For i As Integer = 0 To n
        d(i, 0) = i
    Next

    For j As Integer = 0 To m
        d(0, j) = j
    Next

    ' Step 3
    For i As Integer = 1 To n
        'Step 4
        For j As Integer = 1 To m
            ' Step 5
            Dim cost As Integer = If((s2(j - 1) = s1(i - 1)), 0, 1)

            ' Step 6
            d(i, j) = Math.Min(Math.Min(d(i - 1, j) + 1, d(i, j - 1) + 1), d(i - 1, j - 1) + cost)
        Next
    Next
    ' Step 7
    Return d(n, m)
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Returns a score between 0.0-1.0 indicating how closely two strings match.  1.0 is a 100%
''' T-SQL equality match, and the score goes down from there towards 0.0 for less similar strings.
''' </summary>
<Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction()> _
Public Shared Function GetSimilarityScore(string1 As SqlString, string2 As SqlString) As SqlDouble
    If string1.IsNull OrElse string2.IsNull Then Return SqlInt32.Null

    Dim s1 As String = string1.Value.ToUpper().TrimEnd(" "c)
    Dim s2 As String = string2.Value.ToUpper().TrimEnd(" "c)
    If s1 = s2 Then Return 1.0F ' At this point, T-SQL would consider them the same, so I will too

    Dim flatLevScore As Double = InternalGetSimilarityScore(s1, s2)

    Dim letterS1 As String = GetLetterSimilarityString(s1)
    Dim letterS2 As String = GetLetterSimilarityString(s2)
    Dim letterScore As Double = InternalGetSimilarityScore(letterS1, letterS2)

    'Dim wordS1 As String = GetWordSimilarityString(s1)
    'Dim wordS2 As String = GetWordSimilarityString(s2)
    'Dim wordScore As Double = InternalGetSimilarityScore(wordS1, wordS2)

    If flatLevScore = 1.0F AndAlso letterScore = 1.0F Then Return 1.0F
    If flatLevScore = 0.0F AndAlso letterScore = 0.0F Then Return 0.0F

    ' Return weighted result
    Return (flatLevScore * 0.2F) + (letterScore * 0.8F)
End Function

Private Shared Function InternalGetSimilarityScore(s1 As String, s2 As String) As Double
    Dim dist As SqlInt32 = ComputeLevenstheinDistance(s1, s2)
    Dim maxLen As Integer = If(s1.Length > s2.Length, s1.Length, s2.Length)
    If maxLen = 0 Then Return 1.0F
    Return 1.0F - Convert.ToDouble(dist.Value) / Convert.ToDouble(maxLen)
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Sorts all the alpha numeric characters in the string in alphabetical order
''' and removes everything else.
''' </summary>
Private Shared Function GetLetterSimilarityString(s1 As String) As String
    Dim allChars = If(s1, "").ToUpper().ToCharArray()
    Array.Sort(allChars)
    Dim result As New StringBuilder()
    For Each ch As Char In allChars
        If Char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch) Then
            result.Append(ch)
        End If
    Next
    Return result.ToString()
End Function

''' <summary>
''' Removes all non-alpha numeric characters and then sorts
''' the words in alphabetical order.
''' </summary>
Private Shared Function GetWordSimilarityString(s1 As String) As String
    Dim words As New List(Of String)()
    Dim curWord As StringBuilder = Nothing
    For Each ch As Char In If(s1, "").ToUpper()
        If Char.IsLetterOrDigit(ch) Then
            If curWord Is Nothing Then
                curWord = New StringBuilder()
            End If
            curWord.Append(ch)
        Else
            If curWord IsNot Nothing Then
                words.Add(curWord.ToString())
                curWord = Nothing
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If curWord IsNot Nothing Then
        words.Add(curWord.ToString())
    End If

    words.Sort(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    Return String.Join(" ", words.ToArray())
End Function
```

Comment: Not having access to MDS and thanking that I'm not working with Big Data - this looks like a great fit. Highly appreciate the details.

Comment: Hi @mattmc3, how do I get that CLR UDF into SQL server?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/create-clr-functions?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16

Answer (score 21):

In addition to the other good info here, you might want to consider using the [Double Metaphone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_Metaphone) phonetic algorithm which is generally considered to be better than [SOUNDEX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex).

Tim Pfeiffer details an implementation in SQL in his article [Double Metaphone Sounds Great Convert the C++ Double Metaphone algorithm to T-SQL](https://www.itprotoday.com/software-development/double-metaphone-sounds-great) (originally in [SQL Mag](https://web.archive.org/web/20091207025605/http://www.sqlmag.com:80/Articles/ArticleID/26094/pg/1/1.html) & then in [SQL Server Pro](https://web.archive.org/web/20130725060153/http://sqlmag.com:80/t-sql/double-metaphone-sounds-great)).

That will assist in matching names with slight misspellings, e.g., *Carl* vs. *Karl*.

**Update**: The actual downloadable code seems to be gone, but [here's an implementation found on a github repo](https://github.com/mb16/geocoderNet/blob/master/build/sql/doubleMetaphone.sql) that appears to have cloned the original code

Comment: @Lèsemajesté Link fixed.

Comment: That link is now dead... again

Comment: @codingbadger Works for me. It's also available in the Wayback Machine: [doubleMetaphone.sql](https://web.archive.org/web/20210428122322/https://github.com/mb16/geocoderNet/blob/master/build/sql/doubleMetaphone.sql)

Answer (score 7):

I would use SQL Server Full Text Indexing, which will allow you to do searches and return things that not only contain the word but also may have a misspelling.

Comment: Thand, i have considered it bit se use standard edition and full text search isn't an option here.

Comment: Full Text Search is available in all editions of SQL Server 2005 and 2008

Comment: SQL Server Fulltext indexing does **NOT** support fuzzy search.  When the searched text contains misspellings, it will fail!

Comment: Full Text Indexing - via the CONTAINS() function - supports fuzzy in the sense of 'multiple terms in the vicinity of one another'.  It does not support fuzzy in the sense of 'slightly different spellings'.

Answer (score 7):

Since the first release of Master Data Services, you've got access to more advanced fuzzy logic algorithms than what SOUNDEX implements.  So provided that you've got MDS installed, you'll be able to find a function called **Similarity()** in the **mdq** schema (MDS database).

More info on how it works: http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2011/02/05/finding-similar-strings-with-fuzzy-logic-functions-built-into-mds/

Answer (score 6):

I personally use a CLR implementation of the [Jaro-Winkler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro-Winkler) algorithm which seems to work pretty well - it struggles a bit with strings longer than about 15 characters and doesn't like matching email addresses but otherwise is quite good - full implementation guide can be found [here](http://isolvable.blogspot.com/2011/05/jaro-winkler-fast-fuzzy-linkage.html)

Here is a sample of what that looks like in t-sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM myTable1 as t1 
INNER JOIN myTable2 as t2 
ON dbo.StringDistance(t1.MyField, t2.MyField) > 0.85
```

An advantage of this approach over soundex is that this can more easily handle typos, because if the typo produces different sound then SOUNDEX will not match it correctly.

For example, if you typed “ytpe” instead of “type” then SOUNDEX will not give you a correct match. The codes returned for SOUNDEX(‘ytpe’) and SOUNDEX(‘type’) are the following:

ytpe Y310

type T100

If I use Jaro-Winkler StringDistance(‘ytpe’,’type’) here is what I get 0.91(6), which means it is a good match. Remember 1 – is exact match, so 0.91 is very close to it.

If you are unable to use CLR functions for whatever reasons, maybe you could try running the data through an SSIS package (using the fuzzy transformation lookup) - detailed [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+%28SSIS%29/65616/)

Answer (score 3):

**Part 2 of the code For the link in Redfilter Answer:**

**References:**
https://github.com/mb16/geocoderNet/blob/master/build/sql/doubleMetaphone.sql

```
BEGIN
                        SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'N'
                        SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'KN'
                    END
                                    ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'KN'
                        SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'KN'
                    END
                END
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                    END

                    --'tagliaro'
                    ELSE IF (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 1),@Word,'LI')=1) AND 
(dbo.fnSlavoGermanic(@Word)=0)
                    BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'KL'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'L'
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                    END

                    -- -ges-,-gep-,-gel-, -gie- at beginning
            -- This call to fnStringAt() is the 'worst case' in number of values passed. A UDF that used DEFAULT values instead of
                        -- a multi-valued argument would require ten DEFAULT arguments for EP, EB, EL, etc. (assuming the first was not defined with a DEFAULT).
                    ELSE IF ((@CurrentPosition = 1)
                            AND ((SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1) = 'Y') 
                                    OR (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 
1),@Word,'ES,EP,EB,EL,EY,IB,IL,IN,IE,EI,ER')=1)) )
                    BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'K'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'J'
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                    END

                    -- -ger-,  -gy-
                    ELSE IF (((dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 1), @Word, 'ER')=1) OR 
(SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1) = 'Y'))
                                    AND (dbo.fnStringAt(1, @Word, 'DANGER,RANGER,MANGER')=0)
                                            AND (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition - 1), @Word, 
'E,I,RGY,OGY')=0) )
                    BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'K'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'J'
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                    END

                    -- italian e.g, 'biaggi'
                    ELSE IF (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 1),@Word,'E,I,Y')=1) OR 
(dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition - 1),@Word,'AGGI,OGGI')=1)
                    BEGIN
                            --obvious germanic
                            IF ((dbo.fnStringAt(1,@Word,'VAN ,VON ,SCH')=1)
                                    OR (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 1),@Word,'ET')=1))
                BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'K'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'K'
                END
                            ELSE
                BEGIN
                                    --always soft if french ending
                                    IF (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 1),@Word,'IER ')=1)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'J'
                        SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'J'
                    END
                                    ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'J'
                        SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'K'
                    END
                END
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                    END

            ELSE
            BEGIN
                        IF (SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1) = 'G')
                BEGIN
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                END
                        ELSE
                BEGIN
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
                END
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'K'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'K'
            END
        END

        ELSE IF @CurrentChar = 'H'
        BEGIN
                    --only keep if first & before vowel or btw. 2 vowels
                    IF (((@CurrentPosition = 1) OR 
(dbo.fnIsVowel(SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition - 1,1))=1)) 
                            AND (dbo.fnIsVowel(SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1))=1))
                    BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'H'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'H'
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
            END
                    --also takes care of 'HH'
                    ELSE 
            BEGIN
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
            END
        END

        ELSE IF @CurrentChar = 'J'
        BEGIN
                    --obvious spanish, 'jose', 'san jacinto'
                    IF (dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition,@Word,'JOSE')=1) OR 
(dbo.fnStringAt(1,@Word,'SAN ')=1)
                    BEGIN
                            IF (((@CurrentPosition = 1) AND (SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition 
+ 4,1) = ' ')) OR (dbo.fnStringAt(1,@Word,'SAN ')=1) )
                BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'H'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'H'
                END
                            ELSE
                            BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'J'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'H'
                            END
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
                    END

                    ELSE IF ((@CurrentPosition = 1) AND 
(dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition,@Word,'JOSE')=0))
            BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'J'
                --Yankelovich/Jankelowicz
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'A' 
                        --it could happen!
                        IF (SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1) = 'J') 
                BEGIN
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                END
                        ELSE
                BEGIN
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
                END
            END
                    ELSE
            BEGIN
                            --spanish pron. of e.g. 'bajador'
                            IF( (dbo.fnIsVowel(SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition - 1,1))=1)
                                    AND (dbo.fnSlavoGermanic(@Word)=0)
                                            AND ((SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1) = 'A') OR 
(SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1) = 'O')))
                BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'J'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'H'
                END
                            ELSE
                BEGIN
                                    IF (@CurrentPosition = @WordLength)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'J'
                        SET @MP2 = @MP2 + ''
                    END
                                    ELSE
                    BEGIN
                                            IF ((dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 1), @Word, 
'L,T,K,S,N,M,B,Z')=0) 
                                                            AND (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition - 1), @Word, 
'S,K,L')=0))
                        BEGIN
                            SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'J'
                            SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'J'
                        END
                    END
                END
                        --it could happen!
                        IF (SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1) = 'J') 
                BEGIN
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                END
                        ELSE
                BEGIN
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
                END
            END
        END

        ELSE IF @CurrentChar = 'K'
        BEGIN
                    IF (SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1) = 'K')
            BEGIN
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
            END
                    ELSE
            BEGIN
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
            END
            SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'K'
            SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'K'
        END

        ELSE IF @CurrentChar = 'L'
        BEGIN
                    IF (SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1) = 'L')
                    BEGIN
                            --spanish e.g. 'cabrillo', 'gallegos'
                            IF (((@CurrentPosition = (@WordLength - 3)) 
                                    AND (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition - 
1),@Word,'ILLO,ILLA,ALLE')=1))
                                             OR (((dbo.fnStringAt((@WordLength - 1),@Word,'AS,OS')=1) 
OR (dbo.fnStringAt(@WordLength,@Word,'A,O')=1)) 
                                                    AND (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition - 
1),@Word,'ALLE')=1)) )
                            BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'L'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + ''
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                            END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'L'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'L'
                END
            END
                    ELSE
            BEGIN
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'L'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'L'
            END
        END

        ELSE IF @CurrentChar = 'M'
        BEGIN
                     --'dumb','thumb'
                    IF (((dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition - 1), @Word,'UMB')=1)
                            AND (((@CurrentPosition + 1) = @WordLength) OR 
(dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 2),@Word,'ER')=1)))

                                    OR (SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1) = 'M') )
            BEGIN
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
            END
                    ELSE
            BEGIN
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
            END
            SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'M'
            SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'M'
        END

        ELSE IF @CurrentChar = 'N'
        BEGIN
                    IF (SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1) = 'N')
            BEGIN
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
            END
                    ELSE
            BEGIN
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
            END
            SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'N'
            SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'N'
        END

        ELSE IF @CurrentChar = 'Ñ'
        BEGIN
                        SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
            SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'N'
            SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'N'
        END

        ELSE IF @CurrentChar = 'P'
        BEGIN
                    --What about Michelle Pfeiffer, star of Grease 2? Price-Pfister?, Pfizer?
                    --Don't just look for an 'F' next, what about 'topflight', helpful, campfire, leapfrog, stepfather
                    --Sorry, Mark Knopfler, I don't know how to help you
                    IF (SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1) = 'H')

                OR ((@CurrentPosition = 1) AND 
(SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1) = 'F') AND 
(dbo.fnIsVowel(SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition+2,1))=1))
                    BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'F'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'F'
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                    END

                    --also account for "campbell", "raspberry"
                    ELSE 
            BEGIN
                IF (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 1),@Word, 'P,B')=1)
                BEGIN
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                END
                        ELSE
                BEGIN
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
                END
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'P'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'P'
            END
        END

        ELSE IF @CurrentChar = 'Q'
        BEGIN
                    IF (SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1) = 'Q')
            BEGIN
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
            END
                    ELSE
            BEGIN
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
            END
            SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'K'
            SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'K'
        END

        ELSE IF @CurrentChar = 'R'
        BEGIN
            --QQ: Will SQL short circuit eval? Otherwise, I could try to read before string begins here...
                    --french e.g. 'rogier', but exclude 'hochmeier'
                    IF ((@CurrentPosition = @WordLength)
                            AND (dbo.fnSlavoGermanic(@Word)=0)
                                    AND (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition - 2), @Word, 'IE')=1) 
                                            AND (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition - 4), @Word, 
'ME,MA')=0))
            BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + ''
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'R'
            END
                    ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'R'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'R'
            END

                    IF (SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1) = 'R')
            BEGIN
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
            END
                    ELSE
            BEGIN
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
            END
        END

        ELSE IF @CurrentChar = 'S'
        BEGIN
                    --special cases 'island', 'isle', 'carlisle', 'carlysle'
                    IF (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition - 1), @Word, 'ISL,YSL')=1)
                    BEGIN
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
                    END

                    --special case 'sugar-'
                    ELSE IF ((@CurrentPosition = 1) AND (dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition, 
@Word, 'SUGAR')=1))
                    BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'X'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'S'
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
                    END

                    ELSE IF (dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition, @Word, 'SH')=1)
                    BEGIN
                            --germanic
                            IF (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 1), @Word, 
'HEIM,HOEK,HOLM,HOLZ')=1)
                BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'S'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'S'
                END
                            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'X'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'X'
                END
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                    END

                    --italian & armenian
                    ELSE IF (dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition, @Word, 'SIO,SIA')=1) OR 
(dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition, @Word, 'SIAN')=1)
                    BEGIN
                            IF (dbo.fnSlavoGermanic(@Word)=0)
                BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'S'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'X'
                END
                            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'S'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'S'
                END
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 3
                    END

                    --german & anglicisations, e.g. 'smith' match 'schmidt', 'snider' match 'schneider'
                    --also, -sz- in slavic language altho in hungarian it is pronounced 's'
                    ELSE IF (((@CurrentPosition = 1) 
                                    AND (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 1), @Word, 'M,N,L,W')=1))
                                            OR (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 1), @Word, 'Z')=1))
                    BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'S'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'X'
                            IF (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 1), @Word, 'Z')=1)
                BEGIN
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                END
                            ELSE
                BEGIN
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
                            END
                    END

                    ELSE IF (dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition, @Word, 'SC')=1)
                    BEGIN
                            --Schlesinger's rule
                            IF (SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 2,1) = 'H')
                BEGIN
                                    --dutch origin, e.g. 'school', 'schooner'
                                    IF (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 3), @Word, 
'OO,ER,EN,UY,ED,EM')=1)
                                    BEGIN
                                            --'schermerhorn', 'schenker'
                                            IF (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 3), @Word, 'ER,EN')=1)
                                            BEGIN
                            SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'X'
                            SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'SK'
                        END
                                            ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'SK'
                            SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'SK'
                        END
                                    SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 3
                    END
                                    ELSE
                    BEGIN
                                            IF ((@CurrentPosition = 1) AND 
(dbo.fnIsVowel(SUBSTRING(@Word,3,1))=0) AND (SUBSTRING(@Word,3,1) <> 'W'))
                        BEGIN
                            SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'X'
                            SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'S'
                        END
                                            ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'X'
                            SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'X'
                        END
                                    SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 3
                                    END
                END

                            ELSE IF (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 2), @Word, 'I,E,Y')=1)
                            BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'S'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'S'
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 3
                            END
                            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'SK'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'SK'
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 3
                            END
                    END

                    ELSE 
            BEGIN
                        --french e.g. 'resnais', 'artois'
                IF ((@CurrentPosition = @WordLength) AND 
(dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition - 2), @Word, 'AI,OI')=1))
                BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + ''
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'S'
                END
                        ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'S'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'S'
                END

                        IF (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 1), @Word, 'S,Z')=1)
                BEGIN
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                END
                        ELSE
                BEGIN
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
                END
            END
        END

        ELSE IF @CurrentChar = 'T'
        BEGIN
                    IF (dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition, @Word, 'TION,TIA,TCH')=1)
                    BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'X'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'X'
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 3
            END

                    ELSE IF (dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition, @Word, 'TH,TTH')=1) 
                    BEGIN
                            --special case 'thomas', 'thames' or germanic
                            IF (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 2), @Word, 'OM,AM')=1) 
                                    OR (dbo.fnStringAt(1, @Word, 'VAN ,VON ,SCH')=1) 
                            BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'T'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'T'
                END
                            ELSE    
                BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + '0'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'T'
                            END
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                    END

            ELSE
            BEGIN
                        IF (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 1), @Word, 'T,D')=1)
                BEGIN
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                END
                        ELSE
                BEGIN
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
                END
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'T'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'T'
            END
        END

        ELSE IF @CurrentChar = 'V'
        BEGIN
                    IF (SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1) = 'V')
            BEGIN
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
            END
                    ELSE
            BEGIN
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
            END
            SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'F'
            SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'F'
        END

        ELSE IF @CurrentChar = 'W'
        BEGIN
                    --can also be in middle of word
                    IF (dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition, @Word, 'WR')=1)
                    BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'R'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'R'
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                    END

                    ELSE IF ((@CurrentPosition = 1) 
                            AND ((dbo.fnIsVowel(SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1))=1) 
OR (dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition, @Word, 'WH')=1)))
                    BEGIN
                            --Wasserman should match Vasserman
                            IF (dbo.fnIsVowel(SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1))=1)
                BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'A'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'F'
                END
                            ELSE
                BEGIN
                                    --need Uomo to match Womo
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'A'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'A'
                END
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
                    END

                    --Arnow should match Arnoff
                    ELSE IF (((@CurrentPosition = @WordLength) AND 
(dbo.fnIsVowel(SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition - 1,1))=1)) 
                            OR (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition - 1), @Word, 
'EWSKI,EWSKY,OWSKI,OWSKY')=1) 
                                            OR (dbo.fnStringAt(1, @Word, 'SCH')=1))
                    BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + ''
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'F'
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
            END

                    --polish e.g. 'filipowicz'
                    ELSE IF (dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition, @Word, 'WICZ,WITZ')=1)
                    BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'TS'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'FX'
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 4
            END
    -- skip it
                    ELSE 
            BEGIN
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
            END
        END

        ELSE IF @CurrentChar = 'X'
        BEGIN
                    --french e.g. breaux
                    IF (NOT((@CurrentPosition = @WordLength) 
                            AND ((dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition - 3), @Word, 'IAU,EAU')=1) 
                                            OR (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition - 2), @Word, 
'AU,OU')=1))) )
            BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'KS'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'KS'
            END

                    IF (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 1), @Word, 'C,X')=1)
            BEGIN
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
            END
                    ELSE
            BEGIN
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
            END
        END

        ELSE IF @CurrentChar = 'Z'
        BEGIN
                    --chinese pinyin e.g. 'zhao'
                    IF (SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1) = 'H')
                    BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'J'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'J'
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
            END
                    ELSE
            BEGIN
                            IF ((dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 1), @Word, 'ZO,ZI,ZA')=1) 
                                    OR ((dbo.fnSlavoGermanic(@Word)=1) AND ((@CurrentPosition > 
1) AND SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition - 1,1) <> 'T')))
                            BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'S'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'TS'
                            END
                            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'S'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'S'
                END
                        IF (SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1) = 'Z')
                BEGIN
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                END
                        ELSE
                BEGIN
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
                        END
            END
        END

            ELSE
        BEGIN
                        SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
        END
    END

        --only give back 4 char metaphone
        IF (LEN(@MP1) > 4)
    BEGIN
        SET @MP1 = LEFT(@MP1, 4)
    END
        IF (LEN(@MP2) > 4)
    BEGIN
        SET @MP2 = LEFT(@MP2, 4)
    END
    IF @MP2 = @MP1
    BEGIN
        SET @MP2 = ''
    END

    INSERT @DMP(Metaphone1,Metaphone2) VALUES( @MP1, @MP2 )
    RETURN
END
GO;
------------------------------------------------------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('fnDoubleMetaphoneScalar') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP FUNCTION 
fnDoubleMetaphoneScalar END
GO;
CREATE FUNCTION fnDoubleMetaphoneScalar( @MetaphoneType int, @Word varchar(50) )
RETURNS char(4)
AS
BEGIN
        RETURN (SELECT CASE @MetaphoneType WHEN 1 THEN Metaphone1 
WHEN 2 THEN Metaphone2 END FROM fnDoubleMetaphoneTable( @Word ))
END
```

Answer (score 2):

Pasting RedFilter code in two parts ,so as to avoid link rot

**References:**
https://github.com/mb16/geocoderNet/blob/master/build/sql/doubleMetaphone.sql
**Part1:**

```
--WEB LISTING 1: Double Metaphone Script

-------------------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('fnIsVowel') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP FUNCTION fnIsVowel END
GO;
CREATE FUNCTION fnIsVowel( @c char(1) )
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@c = 'A') OR (@c = 'E') OR (@c = 'I') OR (@c = 'O') OR (@c = 'U') OR (@c = 'Y') 
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1
    END
    --'ELSE' would worry SQL Server, it wants RETURN last in a scalar function
    RETURN 0
END
GO;
-----------------------------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('fnSlavoGermanic') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP FUNCTION fnSlavoGermanic 
END
GO;
CREATE FUNCTION fnSlavoGermanic( @Word char(50) )
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    --Catch NULL also...
    IF (CHARINDEX('W',@Word) > 0) OR (CHARINDEX('K',@Word) > 0) OR 
(CHARINDEX('CZ',@Word) > 0)
    --'WITZ' test is in original Lawrence Philips C++ code, but appears to be a subset of the first test for 'W'
    -- OR (CHARINDEX('WITZ',@Word) > 0)
    BEGIN
        RETURN 1
    END
    --ELSE
        RETURN 0
END
GO;
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
----------------------
--Lawrence Philips calls for a length argument, but this has two drawbacks:
--1. All target strings must be of the same length
--2. It presents an opportunity for subtle bugs, ie fnStringAt( 1, 7, 'Search me please', 'Search' ) returns 0 (no matter what is in the searched string)
--So I've eliminated the argument and fnStringAt checks the length of each target as it executes

--DEFAULTS suck with UDFs. Have to specify DEFAULT in caller - why bother?
IF OBJECT_ID('fnStringAtDef') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP FUNCTION fnStringAtDef END
GO;
CREATE FUNCTION fnStringAtDef( @Start int, @StringToSearch varchar(50), 
    @Target1 varchar(50), 
    @Target2 varchar(50) = NULL,
    @Target3 varchar(50) = NULL,
    @Target4 varchar(50) = NULL,
    @Target5 varchar(50) = NULL,
    @Target6 varchar(50) = NULL )
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    IF CHARINDEX(@Target1,@StringToSearch,@Start) > 0 RETURN 1
    --2 Styles, test each optional argument for NULL, nesting further tests
    --or just take advantage of CHARINDEX behavior with a NULL arg (unless 65 compatibility - code check before CREATE FUNCTION?
    --Style 1:
    --IF @Target2 IS NOT NULL
    --BEGIN
    --  IF CHARINDEX(@Target2,@StringToSearch,@Start) > 0 RETURN 1
    -- (etc.)
    --END
    --Style 2:
    IF CHARINDEX(@Target2,@StringToSearch,@Start) > 0 RETURN 1
    IF CHARINDEX(@Target3,@StringToSearch,@Start) > 0 RETURN 1
    IF CHARINDEX(@Target4,@StringToSearch,@Start) > 0 RETURN 1
    IF CHARINDEX(@Target5,@StringToSearch,@Start) > 0 RETURN 1
    IF CHARINDEX(@Target6,@StringToSearch,@Start) > 0 RETURN 1
    RETURN 0
END
GO;
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('fnStringAt') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP FUNCTION fnStringAt END
GO;
CREATE FUNCTION fnStringAt( @Start int, @StringToSearch varchar(50), @TargetStrings 
varchar(2000) )
RETURNS bit
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SingleTarget varchar(50)
    DECLARE @CurrentStart int
    DECLARE @CurrentLength int

    --Eliminate special cases
    --Trailing space is needed to check for end of word in some cases, so always append comma
    --loop tests should fairly quickly ignore ',,' termination
    SET @TargetStrings = @TargetStrings + ','

    SET @CurrentStart = 1
    --Include terminating comma so spaces don't get truncated
    SET @CurrentLength = (CHARINDEX(',',@TargetStrings,@CurrentStart) - 
@CurrentStart) + 1
    SET @SingleTarget = SUBSTRING(@TargetStrings,@CurrentStart,@CurrentLength)
    WHILE LEN(@SingleTarget) > 1
    BEGIN
        IF SUBSTRING(@StringToSearch,@Start,LEN(@SingleTarget)-1) = 
LEFT(@SingleTarget,LEN(@SingleTarget)-1)
        BEGIN
            RETURN 1
        END
        SET @CurrentStart = (@CurrentStart + @CurrentLength)
        SET @CurrentLength = (CHARINDEX(',',@TargetStrings,@CurrentStart) - 
@CurrentStart) + 1
        IF NOT @CurrentLength > 1 --getting trailing comma 
        BEGIN
            BREAK
        END
        SET @SingleTarget = 
SUBSTRING(@TargetStrings,@CurrentStart,@CurrentLength)
    END
    RETURN 0
END
GO;
------------------------------------------------------------------------
IF OBJECT_ID('fnDoubleMetaphoneTable') IS NOT NULL BEGIN DROP FUNCTION 
fnDoubleMetaphoneTable END
GO;
CREATE FUNCTION fnDoubleMetaphoneTable( @Word varchar(50) )
RETURNS @DMP TABLE ( Metaphone1 char(4), Metaphone2 char(4) )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @MP1 varchar(4), @MP2 varchar(4)
    SET @MP1 = ''
    SET @MP2 = ''
    DECLARE @CurrentPosition int, @WordLength int, @CurrentChar char(1)
    SET @CurrentPosition = 1
    SET @WordLength = LEN(@Word)

    IF @WordLength < 1 
    BEGIN
        RETURN
    END

    --ensure case insensitivity
    SET @Word = UPPER(@Word)

    IF dbo.fnStringAt(1, @Word, 'GN,KN,PN,WR,PS') = 1 
    BEGIN
        SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
    END

    IF 'X' = LEFT(@Word,1)
    BEGIN
        SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'S'
        SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'S'
        SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
    END

    WHILE (4 > LEN(RTRIM(@MP1))) OR (4 > LEN(RTRIM(@MP2)))
    BEGIN
        IF @CurrentPosition > @WordLength 
        BEGIN
            BREAK
        END

        SET @CurrentChar = SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition,1)

        IF @CurrentChar IN('A','E','I','O','U','Y')
        BEGIN
            IF @CurrentPosition = 1 
            BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'A'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'A'
            END
            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
        END
        ELSE IF @CurrentChar = 'B'
        BEGIN
            SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'P'
            SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'P'
            IF 'B' = SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1) 
            BEGIN
                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
            END
            ELSE 
            BEGIN
                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
            END
        END
        ELSE IF @CurrentChar = 'Ç'
        BEGIN
            SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'S'
            SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'S'
            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
        END
        ELSE IF @CurrentChar = 'C'
        BEGIN
            --various germanic
            IF (@CurrentPosition > 2) 
               AND (dbo.fnIsVowel(SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition-2,1))=0) 
               AND (dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition-1,@Word,'ACH') = 1) 
               AND ((SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition+2,1) <> 'I') 
                AND ((SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition+2,1) <> 'E') OR 
(dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition-2,@Word,'BACHER,MACHER')=1)))
            BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'K'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'K'
                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
            END
            -- 'caesar'
            ELSE IF (@CurrentPosition = 1) AND 
(dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition,@Word,'CAESAR') = 1)
            BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'S'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'S'
                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
            END
            -- 'chianti'
            ELSE IF dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition,@Word,'CHIA') = 1
            BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'K'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'K'
                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
            END
            ELSE IF dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition,@Word,'CH') = 1
            BEGIN
                -- Find 'michael'
                IF (@CurrentPosition > 1) AND 
(dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition,@Word,'CHAE') = 1)
                BEGIN
                    --First instance of alternate encoding
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'K'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'X'
                    SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                END
                --greek roots e.g. 'chemistry', 'chorus'
                ELSE IF (@CurrentPosition = 1) AND (dbo.fnStringAt(2, @Word, 
'HARAC,HARIS,HOR,HYM,HIA,HEM') = 1) AND (dbo.fnStringAt(1,@Word,'CHORE') = 0)
                BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'K'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'K'
                    SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                END
                --germanic, greek, or otherwise 'ch' for 'kh' sound
                ELSE IF ((dbo.fnStringAt(1,@Word,'VAN ,VON ,SCH')=1) OR 
                   (dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition-
2,@Word,'ORCHES,ARCHIT,ORCHID')=1) OR 
                   (dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition+2,@Word,'T,S')=1) OR 
                   (((dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition-1,@Word,'A,O,U,E')=1) 
OR 
                   (@CurrentPosition = 1))  
                   AND 
(dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition+2,@Word,'L,R,N,M,B,H,F,V,W, ')=1)))
                BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'K'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'K'
                    SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                END
                ELSE
                BEGIN
                    --is this a given?
                    IF (@CurrentPosition > 1)   
                    BEGIN
                        IF (dbo.fnStringAt(1,@Word,'MC') = 1)
                        BEGIN
                            --eg McHugh
                            SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'K'
                            SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'K'
                        END
                        ELSE
                        BEGIN
                            --Alternate encoding
                            SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'X'
                            SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'K'
                        END
                    END
                    ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'X'
                        SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'X'
                    END
                    SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                END
            END
                    --e.g, 'czerny'
                    ELSE IF (dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition,@Word,'CZ')=1) AND 
(dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition - 2),@Word,'WICZ')=0)
                    BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'S'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'X'
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                    END

                    --e.g., 'focaccia'
                    ELSE IF(dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 1),@Word,'CIA')=1)
                    BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'X'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'X'
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 3
                    END

                    --double 'C', but not if e.g. 'McClellan'
                    ELSE IF(dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition,@Word,'CC')=1) AND NOT 
((@CurrentPosition = 2) AND (LEFT(@Word,1) = 'M'))
                            --'bellocchio' but not 'bacchus'
                            IF (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 2),@Word,'I,E,H')=1) AND 
(dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 2),@Word,'HU')=0)
                            BEGIN
                                    --'accident', 'accede' 'succeed'
                                    IF (((@CurrentPosition = 2) AND 
(SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition - 1,1) = 'A')) 
                                                    OR (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition - 
1),@Word,'UCCEE,UCCES')=1))
                    BEGIN
                        SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'KS'
                        SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'KS'
                    END
                                    --'bacci', 'bertucci', other italian
                                    ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'X'
                        SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'X'
                    END
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 3
                END
                            --Pierce's rule
                            ELSE 
                BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'K'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'K'
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                            END

                    ELSE IF (dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition,@Word,'CK,CG,CQ')=1)
                    BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'K'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'K'
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                    END

                    ELSE IF (dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition,@Word,'CI,CE,CY')=1)
                    BEGIN
                            --italian vs. english
                            IF (dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition,@Word,'CIO,CIE,CIA')=1)
                BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'S'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'X'
                END
                            ELSE
                BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'S'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'S'
                END
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                    END

                    ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'K'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'K'

                        --name sent in 'mac caffrey', 'mac gregor
                        IF (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 1),@Word,' C, Q, G')=1)
                BEGIN
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 3
                END
                        ELSE
                BEGIN
                                IF (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 1),@Word,'C,K,Q')=1)
                                        AND (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 1), 2, 'CE,CI')=0)
                    BEGIN
                                    SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                    END
                                ELSE
                    BEGIN
                                    SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
                    END
                        END
            END

        END
        ELSE IF @CurrentChar = 'D'
        BEGIN
                    IF (dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition, @Word, 'DG')=1)
            BEGIN
                            IF (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 2),@Word,'I,E,Y')=1)
                            BEGIN
                                    --e.g. 'edge'
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'J'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'J'
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 3
                            END
                            ELSE
                BEGIN
                                    --e.g. 'edgar'
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'TK'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'TK'
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                            END
            END
                    ELSE IF (dbo.fnStringAt(@CurrentPosition,@Word,'DT,DD')=1)
                    BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'T'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'T'
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                    END
                    ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'T'
                SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'T'
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
            END
        END

        ELSE IF @CurrentChar = 'F'
        BEGIN
                    IF (SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1) = 'F')
            BEGIN
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
            END
                    ELSE
            BEGIN
                            SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 1
            END
            SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'F'
            SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'F'
        END

        ELSE IF @CurrentChar = 'G'
        BEGIN
                    IF (SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1) = 'H')
                    BEGIN
                            IF (@CurrentPosition > 1) AND 
(dbo.fnIsVowel(SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition - 1,1)) = 0)
                            BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'K'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'K'
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                            END
                                --'ghislane', ghiradelli
                                ELSE IF (@CurrentPosition = 1)
                                BEGIN 
                                        IF (SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 2,1) = 'I')
                    BEGIN
                        SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'J'
                        SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'J'
                    END
                                        ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'K'
                        SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'K'
                    END
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                            END
                            --Parker's rule (with some further refinements) - e.g., 'hugh'
                            ELSE IF (((@CurrentPosition > 2) AND (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition 
- 2),@Word,'B,H,D')=1) )
                                    --e.g., 'bough'
                                    OR ((@CurrentPosition > 3) AND (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition 
- 3),@Word,'B,H,D')=1) )
                                    --e.g., 'broughton'
                                    OR ((@CurrentPosition > 4) AND (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition 
- 4),@Word,'B,H')=1) ) )
                            BEGIN
                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                END
                            ELSE
                BEGIN
                                    --e.g., 'laugh', 'McLaughlin', 'cough', 'gough', 'rough', 'tough'
                                    IF ((@CurrentPosition > 3) 
                                            AND (SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition - 1,1) = 'U') 
                                            AND (dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition - 
3),@Word,'C,G,L,R,T')=1) )
                                    BEGIN
                        SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'F'
                        SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'F'
                    END
                                    ELSE
                    BEGIN
                                            IF ((@CurrentPosition > 1) AND 
SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition - 1,1) <> 'I')
                        BEGIN
                            SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'K'
                            SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'K'
                        END
                    END

                                SET @CurrentPosition = @CurrentPosition + 2
                            END
                    END

                    ELSE IF (SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1) = 'N')
                    BEGIN
                            IF ((@CurrentPosition = 2) AND (dbo.fnIsVowel(LEFT(@Word,1))=1) AND 
(dbo.fnSlavoGermanic(@Word)=0))
                            BEGIN
                    SET @MP1 = @MP1 + 'KN'
                    SET @MP2 = @MP2 + 'N'
                END
                            ELSE
                BEGIN
                                    --not e.g. 'cagney'
                                    IF ((dbo.fnStringAt((@CurrentPosition + 2),@Word,'EY')=0) 
                                                    AND (SUBSTRING(@Word,@CurrentPosition + 1,1) <> 
'Y') AND (dbo.fnSlavoGermanic(@Word)=0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SOUNDEX and related DIFFERENCE function in SQL Server to find similar names. The reference on MSDN is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187384.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Regarding de-duping things your string split and match is great first cut. If there are known items about the data that can be leveraged to reduce workload and/or produce better results, it is always good to take advantage of them. Bear in mind that often for de-duping it is impossible to entirely eliminate manual work, although you can make that much easier by catching as much as you can automatically and then generating reports of your "uncertainty cases."

Regarding name matching: SOUNDEX is horrible for quality of matching and especially bad for the type of work you are trying to do as it will match things that are too far from the target. It's better to use a combination of double metaphone results and the Levenshtein distance to perform name matching. With appropriate biasing this works really well and could probably be used for a second pass after doing a cleanup on your knowns.

You may also want to consider using an SSIS package and looking into Fuzzy Lookup and Grouping transformations (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345128(SQL.90).aspx).

Using SQL Full-Text Search (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc879300.aspx) is a possibility as well, but is likely not appropriate to your specific problem domain.

Answer (score 0):

do it this way

```
         create table person(
         personid int identity(1,1) primary key,
         firstname varchar(20),
         lastname varchar(20),
         addressindex int,
         sound varchar(10)
         )
```

and later on create a trigger

```
         create trigger trigoninsert for dbo.person
         on insert 
         as
         declare @personid int;
         select @personid=personid from inserted;
         update person
         set sound=soundex(firstname) where personid=@personid;
```

now what i can do is i can create a procedure which looks something like this

```
         create procedure getfuzzi(@personid int)
          as
         declare @sound varchar(10);
         set @sound=(select sound from person where personid=@personid;
         select personid,firstname,lastname,addressindex from person
         where sound=@sound
```

this will  return you all the names that are nearly in match with the names provided by for a particular personid