# Fuzzy match on names

Tags: sql-server-2008, lucene, solr, full-text-search

Anybody have experience with fuzzy matching with sql server fulltext indexes on names like
searching for Bob Thornton would return results like Bobby Thornton?

I guess Lucene.Net and Solr could be used for this as well but nice to do it all in the database.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: similar question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921978/fuzzy-matching-using-t-sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921978/fuzzy-matching-using-t-sql)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure whether this counts as 'all in the database', but [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141026.aspx) has a fuzzy matching block which provides this functionality.