# Search for same Values in two SQL TABLES

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

- Table 1 with columns `Number` and `TEXT`
- Table 2 with columns `Number` and `TEXT`

Now Table 1 has `Nr = 12345AB` and Table 2 `Nr = 00012345AB`

How can I find all columns from **Table 1** that are not in **Table 2**?

Comment: Try writing some SQL.

Comment: NOT IN or NOT EXISTS might be of help

Comment: Are you trying to find columns? or rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this select:

```
select 
  * 
from 
  table1 t1 
  left join table2 t2 on t1.number=t2.number 
where 
  t2.number is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Try ***exists***:

```
  select t1.*
    from Table1 t1
   where not exists (select 1
                       from Table2 t2
                      where t2.Number = t1.Number)
```

Comment: Yes you're right, minus is not a standard solution. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think he is looking for a fuzzy match.  In which case =, LIKE, CONTAINS will not work.  You will need to roll your own similar to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064445/sql-fuzzy-matching).

Answer (score 0):

```
    This is also a method but its too lengthy :-)

        SELECT table1.*
        FROM table2
        WHERE (number NOT IN
            (SELECT number 
             FROM table2)) AND (text NOT IN
            (SELECT text 
             FROM table2))
```