# mysql like with all permutation of words

Tags: mysql, sql-like

Helo to all

for example I have row with this filed name :   "Happy cow milk";

if I search for "Happy milk" with using "%Happy%milk%" it works, now I want to get this result with this query : "milk Happy" or "milk cow"...

how to I do it ?
thanks in advance .

Comment: You need to look into [Full text searching](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Fuzzy Matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064445/sql-fuzzy-matching)

Comment: Just break all words into multiple rows and store them in another table.

Comment: NO NO NO NO just full text searching solve the problem <3 thank you @Nick

Comment: @Marcin That question is about sql-server, not mysql.

Comment: @Barmar I used it in mysql see the answer below

Comment: @kiamoz Your answer doesn't use anything from the question Marcin linked to.

Comment: @Barmar , Marchin's  answer not belongs to my question

Comment: I know, that's what I meant in my comment to him. I don't know why you told me to see your answer.

Comment: it's my bad, ;) @Barmar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html
solve the problem !

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE MATCH(col1, col2)
AGAINST('search terms' IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE)
```