# SQL fuzzy match query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, fuzzy-search, fuzzy-comparison

I have a **uaserData** table with users infromation. It has `Id`, `firstname` , `lastname` and many more. So in that table if I have 'like below' two persons with the `firstname` and  `lastname` are the same they are most likely duplicates. (can be spelling mistakes)

```
Id     1
firstname    "kim"
lastname     "kardashian"

Id     2
firstname    "kem"
lastname     "kardshian"
```

I know how do this if I were to match exactly on all columns but I need fuzzy match to do.
There are fuzzy match examples but it very difficult to understand. SOUNDEX also not helping much.

Answer (score 0):

there are bunch af similar questions answered
as example: [SQL Fuzzy Matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20064445/sql-fuzzy-matching)

this is as SOUNDEX example

```
Declare @t Table (FName varchar(20) ,  LName varchar(20))

insert into @t Values
('kim'    ,'kardashian')
,('kem'     ,'kardashian')
,('klm'     ,'kardashian')

select *
from @t
where SOUNDEX('kam') = SOUNDEX(FName)
```

[image]